# What is the best default search order - on a within-site product search?

Tags: search

Sites tend to use 'most relevant' (however that's defined !) as the default search order.

Is this the best default from a users' point of view - or would another option, like Price (Low>High) be better ?

Answer (score 1):

Normally **I use price low to height when my customers are just looking for price, this is common at very competitive markets and by relevance or most bought when quality is important for customers, mainly on brands websites** but everything depends on:

- Who are your users?
- What they are looking for?
- What is most important for theirs?
- What is really relevant to them?

You can create a good persona and then will be easier to define this question.

If you don't have enough time and budget you can take some decision based on what your stronger competitor is doing.

See these links to know how to create personas:

https://uxplanet.org/how-to-create-personas-step-by-step-guide-303d7b0d81b4
https://uxmastery.com/create-ux-personas/

Answer (score 1):

I'm with @Stacey, it depends on site and what type of products they sell.

I personally would not have the low to high as the default, for the same reason as Stacy said with ebay and Amazon it creates weird and unrelated product results. Plus it could also devaluate the site, you would loose the premium feel. Main thing is to give users the choice to switch to what they need easily. Give them the options and tools to do what they want.

I would suggest as an alternative 'Newest first', but again it depends on what the site sells.

Track the interactions and stats from user visits and see if you made the right choice. Make sure you tag the options so that you can view what was more successful for conversion. Not necessarily which filter/ordering option was most common but which option converted the best. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the algorithm that's fueling the "most relevant" results. Too often, the company is using this to push products that it really wants you to buy, but often it's used to show products that would be the best fit based on a user's profile and site behavior (such as what other pages they've visited and queries they've entered.)

Sometimes the algorithm learns what other users started a search with, and ultimately bought, and that informs the relevancy of a product.

The problem with using Price (Low > High) is that sometimes a query returns items that are of a lower price, but not what the user is really seeking. For example, on Ebay, when I [search on "trombone"](https://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_from=R40&_nkw=trombone&_sacat=0&LH_TitleDesc=0&_sop=15&_blrs=recall_filtering), only one of the first few dozen results is an actual trombone. I see trombone parts, accessories, toy versions, etc. Relevancy solves this problem.